# Error al vincular un archivo de validación en xml con un archivo dtd

Tags: html, xml, validación, xhtml

Hola chicos estoy validando un archivo xml con un archivo externo dtd, pero me da el siguiente error, a continuación muestro el código y su fallo en imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE incidencias SYSTEM "LMGSI04.dtd">
<incidencias>
    <cabecera>
        <proveedor id="PR001" nombre="Reparaciones eléctricas Pepe Vatios" />
        <fechas desde="2021-01-01T00:00:00Z" hasta="2021-01-02T00:00:00Z" transmision="2021-01-02T00:00:05Z" />
    </cabecera>
    <siniestros>
            <encurso>
                <siniestro id="S21000089">
                    <cliente nombre="Sonia Murillo Gómez" direccion="c/ Mayor, 1 30201" localidad="Cartagena" movil="634567891" />
                    <descripcion>
                        Fogonazo en el enchufe donde tiene una estufa encendida.
                    </descripcion>
                    <presupuesto horas="1.0" desplazamiento="30" importe="36.00" />
                </siniestro>
            </encurso>
           
    </siniestros>
</incidencias>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el plugin de Notepad++  que estás usando (probablemente "XML Tools": debes indicar esto al preguntar!) por defecto valida si "por error agregaste un DTD al documento". Creo que es porque actualmente se prefiere/aconseja usar XSD en lugar de DTD.

## Solución:

En Notepad++, has clic en Plugins > Xml Tools > Options, y donde dice "Prohibit DTD" ponlo en FALSE. Así, en lugar de decir que no debes usar un DTD, leerá el DTD y hará la validación correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Listo funcionando, gracias @Roimer, está solucionado !! doy la respuesta por válida un saludo !